# Model factory generar claves foráneas relacionadas

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero que al asignar un país aleatorio, se asigne una comunidad de forma aleatoria de ese país y que después se asigne una provincia aleatoria de esa comunidad, ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use App\Address;

$factory->define(Address::class, function (Faker $faker) {
 return [
    'address' => $faker->streetAddress,
    'address2' => $faker->streetAddress,
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
    'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    'user_id' => App\User::all()->random()->id,
    'postcode' => $faker->postcode,
    'city' => $faker->city,
    'country_id' => App\Country::all()->random()->id,
    'community_id' => App\Community::all()->random()->id, 
    'province_id' => App\Province::all()->random()->id,
    'dni' => $faker->unixTime,
    'company' => $faker->company,
    'area_id' => App\Area::all()->random()->id, 
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes cargar un país aleatorio con sus relaciones respectivas, y posteriormente obtener una comunidad aleatoria de la colección de dicha relación.

Es más fácil de entender en la práctica:

```
// obtenemos todos los países con sus relaciones
$countries = App\Country::with(['communities', 'provinces'])->get();

$factory->define(Address::class, function (Faker $faker) use ($countries) {

    // un país al azar de la colección y de ese país obtenemos una comunidad
    // y de esa comunidad, obtenemos una provincia
    $country = $countries->random();
    $community = $country->communities->random();
    $province = $community->provinces->random();

 return [
    'address' => $faker->streetAddress,
    'address2' => $faker->streetAddress,
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
    'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    'user_id' => App\User::all()->random()->id,
    'postcode' => $faker->postcode,
    'city' => $faker->city,
    'country_id' => $country->id,
    'community_id' => $community->id, 
    'province_id' => $province->id,
    'dni' => $faker->unixTime,
    'company' => $faker->company,
    'area_id' => App\Area::all()->random()->id, 
  ];
});
```

La respuesta es Eager Loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading